# php included form acting strangley with Firefox

Tags: php, sql, firefox

For some reason when I call a function to create a form, the drop down menus aren't sticky and the browser forces users to click into the first text field and tab through the rest. It won't let them mouse through the fields. This is only happening in FF, not IE or Chrome. The forms I'm including are just basic html and only php pages I include are doing this.

Here is one function:

```
function addNoteUI($keyword) {

echo "<div id='search_result_right'>";
echo "<center><div id='enter_note_header'>Assign a Salesperson</div></center><p>";

echo "<form id='response' action='notes_add.php' method='post'>";

echo "<label for='mod_num'>MOD Initials: <label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='mod_num' size='2' maxlength='4'><p>";

echo "<label for='sales_num'>Assigned to Sales Person: <label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='sales_num' size='2' maxlength='4'><p>";

echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_num' value='$keyword'>";

echo "<label for='response'>Note</label><br>";
echo "<textarea name='response' cols='30' rows='7 maxlength='510'></textarea><p>";

echo "<input type='submit' value='Assign'>";
echo "</form>";

echo "</div>";
```

Here is the other:

```
function changeDept() {
include 'ask_search.php';
echo "<div id='search_result'>";
echo "<form action='change_dept.php' method='post'>";

echo "<label for='current_num'>Enter the Question Number to be Changed: <label>";
echo "<input type='text' name='current_num' size='4'><p>";

echo "<label for='store'>Select New Store/Department: <label>";
echo "<select name='store'>";
    echo "<option>Please Select</option>";
    echo "<option value='Albany'>Sales (Albany Store)</option>";
    echo "<option value='Saratoga'>Sales (Saratoga Store)</option>";
    echo "<option value='Web Sales'>Sales (TaftFurniture.com)</option>";
    echo "<option value='Financing'>Financing</option>";
    echo "<option value='Customer Service'>Customer Service</option>";
    echo "<option value='Delivery'>Delivery</option>";
    echo "<option value='HR'>Human Resources</option>";
    echo "<option value='Web Contact'>Website Comment</option>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Change' id='dropdown'>";
echo "</select></form></div>";
```

}
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your html code?

Comment: it would be better if you can post myform.php and the page where you have included this.

Comment: php has nothing to do with the browser. problem is in client side if in one browser it is working, and in other, it isn't.

Comment: Firefox has no clude that PHP generated this form. It just sees HTML coming out of the server. If there's a problem with firefox, it's almost guaranteed to have nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Problem was with my code, didn't close label tags correctly in 3 spots, FF had trouble with it while Chrome and IE didn't. Thanks for the help! @Marcovecchio

Answer (score 4):

Your labels are not closing properly:

```
echo "<label for='mod_num'>MOD Initials: <label>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<label for='mod_num'>MOD Initials: </label>";
```

Also, in the second example, you have an input inside the select. The input must be outside:

```
    echo "<option value='Web Contact'>Website Comment</option>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Change' id='dropdown'>";
echo "</select></form></div>";
```

Should be:

```
    echo "<option value='Web Contact'>Website Comment</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Change' id='dropdown'></form></div>";
```

And another one, you're not closing your P tags:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='mod_num' size='2' maxlength='4'><p>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<p><input type='text' name='mod_num' size='2' maxlength='4'></p>";
```

Try to be more careful with your tags. Some browsers are more forgiving about malformed HTML, but others are not.

Comment: Added a new comment to the answer, see if this one solves your problem.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Glad to help! If you can mark the answer as accepted, that would be great, thank you.